# node.js: How to differentiate between two forms on server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, form-submit

I have two forms on my html page:

```
<form id="enterForm" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <textarea id="queries" name="queries"></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
<form id="uploadForm" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="file" name="upload"><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

On the server side, I have to call corresponding functions based on which form's submit button was pressed.

Currently, I am doing like this:

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url == '/upload' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
        processFile(req, res);
    }
    else if (req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
        processField(req, res);
    }
}
```

My question is, is there any other way for server to find out which form's submit button was pressed? Ideally, I would like to keep the url same for both the forms.

Comment: A dumb and easy solution is to put a hidden input inside each form that identifies the form.

Comment: Can you let me know what should be written in the server side to read that hidden input?

Comment: This is a different question, it will be listed in your POST data, assuming `<input type="hidden" name="formName" value="enterForm">. You would look for "formName" in the POST. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js

Comment: Different `action` urls and different input names should suffice to distinguish them, shouldn't they?

Comment: @Bergi I want to keep same urls. As pointed out by user286... , hidden input solves the problem.

Comment: You should think about using [`express`](http://expressjs.com/), then you could just distinguish them by their `action`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a hidden form field on each form.

```
<form id="enterForm" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <textarea id="queries" name="queries"></textarea><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="formInstance" value="form1" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</fieldset>
</form>
<form id="uploadForm" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <input type="file" name="upload"><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="formInstance" value="form2" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Then on the server, you could parse the request body to see what value is assigned to formInstance. However, this requires quite a few lines of code if you're not using a module to help parse the body. So, you might want to use a module like [node-formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable). Then you could do something like the following.

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url == '/' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
            if(fields.formInstance == 'form1') {
                processField(req, res); 
            }
            else if(fields.formInstance == 'form2') {
                processFile(req, res);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.